# Recovering data on an MBR partition converted to GPT

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, data-recovery, mbr, gpt

first time poster but I've been a long time reader! Here goes...

I've just converted a WD Green, 2TB HDD (data only) NTFS - using Minitool Partition Wizard 9.1 from MBR to GPT. Drive was about 67% full.

Using Windows 10. I have a UEFI GPT boot drive. The website specifically said this does not lose data!  Using the convert mbr to gpt command only took a couple of seconds (should it have been a long process?)

It now shows up as Basic GPT - Unallocated - empty space. 
Also no drive letter is assigned.

Its not a system disk so no activity should have over written any data yet.

Before I try to recover the partition, does anyone have any experience - should I:

1 - first convert the drive BACK to MBR then try and recover the data?

or

2 - Is it safer to stick with the GPT and attempt recovery from its current type?

or

3 - Assign a driveletter and reboot, maybe the system will then see the GPT?

Thanks for any help! 
AP

Comment: probably not, being an early post I probably didnt word it correctly, the main thrust was trying to figure out if I could recover the partition, from gpt back to mbr - the data recovery was a follow on angle if I couldnt get that to work. Also, if changin back to mbr from gpt would help in trying torecover the partition. I never did work that out. The drive recovery is on hold until I have time off from work again. Ill leave an update if I get a solution.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you won't recover your MBR because it's been overwritten (unless using advanced and expensive techniques...).

However, as long as the disk content hasn't been changed, recovery tools could be able to identify the old partitions (by their sector 0), and since you were using NTFS, they should also be able to spot the MFT.

I'd say recovering your partitions seems compromised, recovering data should be quite possible.

Also if you had only one partition, you can recreate it easily.

If possible, make a backup of your harddisk prior to any writing.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, its good to get another perspective.  I get your point about the mbr being lost - I remember many years ago recovering a different drive and there was an mbr backup somewhere on the drive, or maybe it was NTFS - something like that.   But I get your point, it cant recreate the mbr if I switch it back to that system.  But as you say the data hasnt been overwritten, only the way it is "pointed to" - so I htink you have answeredmy question.

Comment: Many years ago, when recovering a different drive there was an mbr backup on the drive, or maybe NTFS - MFT.

I cant recreate the mbr even if I switch it back.
Am I right that it is possible to back up an mbr? It would have been great for minitools to do that. 

The data hasn't been overwritten, only the way it is "pointed to" - so you have answered the question. I'll scan the disk in GPT and report back.

I've emailed Minitool to ask them what they think, after all their page was very explicit, no data would be lost! 

I guess if I can recover it then technically it isn't 
;)

Comment: ok - just getting used to the way this forum works! with answering, editing time limits, word limits etc...  ;)

Comment: There's no MBR backup. You're probably mixing it with MFT which has a backup (and so does GPT). You may give a look at [link](https://www.runtime.org/data-recovery-software.htm) GetDataBack. They have a simple version now, I always go with the classic. The software runs in demo until registered. The idea is to get it to scan your drive, it will then report valid MFTs it found. From there you should be able to recover your files. However I have a little doubt: how is sector offset stored in MFT? Absolute or relative to MFT should be ok, relative to partition would be an issue. Try it.

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, the correct way to handle any kind of data loss scenario is to do a bit copy of the drive onto another drive, and attempt recovery on that.

An intermediate step would be to back up the first sector of your drive - which is where the MBR is stored.

If you are a little bit risk tolerant, you should be able to have Testdisk scan your disk, find the partitions and fix them - it probably won't make the disk bootable, but it should make the data visible.  While there is always risk, Testdisk is a relatively low risk procedure.